# TemplateInputException during execution of jar in the repository target

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar

I'm going to run a web app on spring boot with jar file. After compilation of the app I move to repository target and run the jar file. After opening of tab in browser the terminal shows next problem:

```
2022-08-05 09:50:42.312 ERROR 19502 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [/farmer/farmer1], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers] with root cause
```

It's strange because during execution my app in the Intellij IDEA there is no such problem and all templates are founded.

I would be grateful for your help to run the app with jar file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of my problem. Method in controller returned "/farmer/farmer1". But it should return String without first "/" e.g. "farmer/farmer1".